# How to query with a join with linq to sql

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to query for gifts given a term from my categories table. Entity Framework created a bridge table to connect my "Gift" with my "GiftCategroies". But the query I have yielded no results.

From DbContext:

```
public DbSet<Gift> Gifts { get; set; }
public DbSet<GiftCategory> Categories { get; set; }
```

The two entities I created:

```
public class Gift
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<GiftCategory> Categories { get; set; }
    public int Rating { get; set; }
}

public class GiftCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Gift> Gifts { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my query to try and fetch the gifts given a giftcategory term. No results returned. I'm not sure if I even need a join for this type of query.

```
var model =
    from gifts in db.Gifts
    join giftCategory in db.Categories on gifts.Id equals giftCategory.Id
    where giftCategory.Name.Contains(searchTerm)
    select gifts;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use navigation properties instead of joins:

```
var gifts = (from c in db.Categories
             from g in c.Gifts
             where c.Name.Contains(searchTerm)
             select g).Distinct().ToList();
```